# What's is the right way to trigger an error callback in Backbone if my response has a certain flag?

Tags: backbone.js, fetch

This is my use case: I call fetch on a collection and receive a JSON from my server yet I have an error flag. This will always trigger the success flow, and I can detect the error by 2 means:

1. In my parse method - which is ugly.
2. By not using the success option, and using the Deferred's Done callback to check for the error. This is ugly as well since I have to call parse myself afterwards.

This would be solveable if Backbone had a validate function on collection but it doesn't...

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I know there's a way to do it by supplying my own Sync method but I got a bit lost there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good question.. I'm not sure it's so bad to work with the parse method. It's name doesn't fit but it's all you've got in the natural path of the code and I guess you can just return an empty list without breaking anything.

The question to me is what is the cause of the error? If it's, say, a permissions thing (or some other error covered by the http protocol), you could return an error code from the server which should trigger your error callback..

Comment: The cause of the error is invalid data in the request. The third-party API adds the error into the JSON.